# GeoServer behind k8s ingress controller

Tags: geoserver

I have deployed the oscarfonts/geoserver container in a kubernetes cluster behind an NGINX ingress controller. The ingress controller is set up to route /geoserver to this service while rewriting the URL to strip the geoserver prefix. The only issue with this is that any URLs coming from geoserver do not include the /geoserver prefix (as the ingress controller doesn't 'put it back in'), e.g. /geoserver/geoserver/ will redirect to /geoserver, but /geoserver/geoserver/index.html works fine.

```
# Source: geoserver/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: RELEASE-NAME-geoserver
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: geoserver-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: geoserver
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 75M
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "myhost"
      secretName: aks-ingress-tls
  rules:
    - host: "myhost"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /geoserver(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: RELEASE-NAME-geoserver
              servicePort: 31006
```

Comment: did you set the proxy_url in the global settings page of GeoServer?

Comment: It wont let me save any changes I make to the page

Comment: you probably need to go in directly via localhost:8080 until the proxy is fixed